# here "Page" refer to "Tab"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

> "Write “Triggers” on the second tab and insert several sheets of paper. On the first page, write down those things that, if they occur, might cause an increase in your symptoms"
>
> On the next page, develop a plan of what you can do, if a trigger come up, to comfort yourself and keep your reactions from becoming more serious symptoms.

my question-1
why here  mentioned on the "first page" instead "first tab"?
It is correct?

then on  second paragraph also he mentioned "on next page"

My question -2
here  "Page" refer to  "Tab"??

I understand point but I get little confuse this "word usage". bcoze I am a new learner.

Comment: "_Because_ I am a new learner". You don't say where these instructions come from, but it sounds as though they refer to a looseleaf binder with things like [this](https://www.euroffice.co.uk//product/manilla-a4-divider-12-part-pink-with-multi-colour-tabs/afp089?AFF=LIAFP089&utm_marin=mkwid_sdkNFsOx9-dc_slid__productid_AFP089_) to divide it into sections. the 'first page' is the first of the 'several sheets of paper' you are told to put in the second section.

Comment: It definitely seems that you're missing out part of the instructions, which makes it hard to know the context. What have you been told to collect and use? What are you provided with?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Page, presumably refers to the sheets of paper that you inserted after the tab.

The writer is talking about organising ring binder. The ["tabs" are sheets of card](https://www.euroffice.co.uk//product/manilla-a4-divider-12-part-pink-with-multi-colour-tabs/afp089?AFF=LIAFP089&utm_marin=mkwid_sdkNFsOx9-dc_slid__productid_AFP089_) which can be used to divide and organise the ring binder. You will have a "tab" with "triggers, and then several sheets of ordinary paper. You then write a list of things that make your symptoms worse on the first piece of paper and your plan on the second piece of paper.